# Google sheets Import XML (importxml) error

Tags: html, xml, excel, xpath, google-sheets

From the website http://www.carsguide.com.au/buy-a-car/all-new-and-used/all-states/all-locations/all-bodytypes/all-makes?sortBy=price&orderBy=asc&searchOffset=0

I am trying to import the field "carListing" (I want the descriptions of these cars)

I have looked at XPath and am very confused by it.

In cell A1 I have http://www.carsguide.com.au/buy-a-car/all-new-and-used/all-states/all-locations/all-bodytypes/all-makes?.

In cell B1 I have  `=importxml(A1,"//a*/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/")`

But the result is an error.  What's the correct XPath expression for this HTML structure?

Comment: can you specify which part of the description  - e.g. what details are most important to you. I can point you to the correct xpath for any field - but you need to be more specific - there are many fields that could be considered a description but no field called description

Answer (score 0):

Don't see any cells so what do you mean by A1, B1?.
Tip: just tried to get contents from Google Calendar and it turned out that's not so easy because of the javascript but you can get content via the Google Calendar API. So might be wort a look for you whether they have an API for Sheets.